# Play 2.3 - play fingerprinting with require.js

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

How can I use the Play framework Asset fingerprinting `@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/main/staticPage.js")` with require.js ?

Play framework requires the main.js (main config file for require.js) to be present and have the configuration for require.js in that.
My main.js looks like :

```
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl : "/assets/javascripts",
        paths : {
            // Public libraries
            "jquery":"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min",

            "all_clients": "../templates/admin/all_clients",             // Need to have this file fingerprinted 
            "all_sites":"../templates/admin/all_sites",                  // Need to have this file fingerprinted 
            "all_adProvider": "../templates/admin/all_adProvider",       // Need to have this file fingerprinted 
               }

    });
})(requirejs);
```

Or how can I achieve fingerprinting with require.js ?

Thanks 
Puneet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will look into "https://github.com/neomaclin/sbt-simple-url-update ". It looks good.

Currently, I am doing something like this in the mainPage.scala.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/requirejs/require.js")"></script>

<script>
requirejs.config({
    paths : {
        jquery:"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min",
        dusthelper:"@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/dust-helpers.js")"+"?noext",
        chart : "@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/Chartconfig.js")"+"?noext"
    }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/main/staticPage.js")"></script>
```